# gifs not loops in ffmpeg movie filter

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif

I have a gif that loops infinite(loop.gif). I want to overlay this gif to top left corner of video.mpg. So I am using this code to make this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -vf "movie=loop.gif [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:10 [out]" -vcodec mpeg2video out.mpg
```

The problem is; gif loops only 1 time and last frame of the gif showing until end of video.mpg.

How can I loop this gif continuously?

Comment: I am using ffmpeg executable in my program. I will remember your notice next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-ignore_loop` option from the GIF demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i loop.gif -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

- See the [GIF demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#gif-1) or run `ffmpeg -h demuxer=gif` for more options.
- No need to use the `movie` source filter.
- This example uses the `shortest` option in the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay). Otherwise the encoding will run indefinitely due to the looping GIF.

Comment: Is there a way to this while preserving the audio track of the first input video file?

Comment: @domji84 The default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) should have included it. If not, then you'll have to use [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The strange thing is it works on some mp4's and not others. The stream types and fps etc all seem to be the same. Not sure why it would work with some and not others..

Comment: I found out to properly map the audio from the input video to the output: ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i test.gif -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4